# Do not show the selected item of first dropdown in second dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdownlist which shows places in my asp.net MVC(C#) application.

The First dropdownlist is to show the "From Place" and the second dropdownlist is to show the "To Place".

The list of Places are say like :

```
 Alabama
 Alaska
 California
 Maryland,.....
```

The `From and To Place` dropdownlists contains the above places. When i select a place in the `From place` dropdownlist, the `To place` dropdownlist should contain the places other than that selected in the `From place` dropdownlist.

How can i do it using jquery? or any other effective way to do it?

Comment: How about disabling the item instead of taking it off the list?

Comment: it should atleast show/hide based on the list in "From Place",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is very useful:

```
$('#FromPlace').change(function() {
   $('#ToPlace >option').remove();
   var options = '';
   options += '<option value="">' + "--Select Place--" + '</option>';
   $("#FromPlace option").map(function(a, b) {
       b.value != '' && $("#FromPlace option:selected").val() != b.value ? options += '<option value="' + b.value + '">' + b.text + '</option>' : '';
   });
   $("select#ToPlace").html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope that helps:

http://codeleacher.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/how-to-addremove-items-from-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to put them in the update panel, and bind the **selectedindexchange** event to the **FROM PLACE DROPDOWNLIST**, when the request is posted to the server remove the listitem of the **TO PLACE dropdownlist** based on the selected index of the **FROM PLACE DROPDOWNLIST**.
And on the first page visit you can disable the **TO PLACES DROPDOWNLIST** and force the user to select first from **FROM PLACED DROPDOWNLIST**.

Comment: Is there a way using jquery? i am using asp.net mvc as it may be unnecessary to go for updatepanel.